# Case sensitive file extension and existence checking

Tags: java, file, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, file-exists

I need to check whether or not a file exists. Which can be accomplished by `File#exists()` method. But this existence checking is case sensitive. I mean if I have a file name some_image_file.jpg in code but if physically the file is some_image_file.JPG then this method says that the file doesn't exists. How can I check the file existence with case insensitivity to the extension and get the actual file name?

In my scenario, I have a excel file. Each row contains metadata for files and the filename. In some cases I have only the filename or other cases I can have full path. I am denoting a row as a document.

These files are placed in the server. My job is to

- Read the excel file row by row and list all the documents.
- Take out the filename or filepath.
- Create the full path of the file.
- Check if the file exists or not.
- Validate other metadata/information provided in the document.
- Upload the file.

My application throws exception in case the file doesn't exists or if some metadata are invalid.

The excel file is written by the customer and they wrote some file name wrong, I mean if the file physically have the extension in lower case, they have written the extension in upper case, also the converse is true.

I am running the application in unix server.

As the file extensions are not matching so the `File#exists()` is giving false and eventually my code is throwing exception.

The folders where the files are placed can have 30000 or more files.

What I want is

- To take the full path of the file.
- Check if the file exists or not.
- If it does not exists then
- Check the file existence by converting the case of the extension.
- If it doesn't exist after the case conversion then throw exception.
- If it exists, then return the actual file name or file path.

If the file name has file extension something like **.Jpg**, don't know what to do! Should I check it by permuting it by changing the case?

Comment: Just to check - you're running on Windows, right? (On a case-sensitive file system, the question doesn't make as much sense.) I've just tried using `File.exists` myself, deliberately specifying the wrong filename case, and it works fine...

Comment: @JonSkeet I am running in UNIX.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense in terms of the behaviour of `File.exists`  - but less sense in terms of why you'd want to do this. Where are you getting the filename from? What information *can* you rely on?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am getting file name by parsing excel file. In my requirement I need to read the excel file, take the file filename and other metadata, check the file existence and upload the file along with the metadata in content server. In some cases the file physically present as .JPG but in excel it is .jpg also the reverse is true. So when I am reading the filename from the excel file as .jpg and the file actually has .JPG and I am checking if the file exists or not then I am getting false.

Comment: So is the filename you read an absolute one? How do you know which directory to look in? (It would be very helpful if you'd update the question with all this sort of information - it makes it much harder to help you if we have to ask for information one piece after another.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated my question explaining the whole scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way I had solved the problem:

```
public String getActualFilePath() {
    File givenFile = new File(filePath);
    File directory = givenFile.getParentFile();

    if(directory == null || !directory.isDirectory()) {
        return filePath;
    }


    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    Map<String, String> fileMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(File file : files) {                        
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            continue;
        }

        String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        fileMap.put(absolutePath, StringUtils.upperCase(absolutePath));
    }

    int noOfOcc = 0;
    String actualFilePath = "";

    for(Entry<String, String> entry : fileMap.entrySet()) {
        if(filePath.toUpperCase().equals(entry.getValue())) {
            actualFilePath = entry.getKey();
            noOfOcc++;
        }
    }

    if(noOfOcc == 1) {
        return actualFilePath;
    }

    return filePath;
}
```

Here `filePath` is the full path to the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the file names in a folder with

```
File.list()
```

and check names by means of

```
equalsIgnoreCase()
```

Or try http://commons.apache.org/io/
and use

```
FileNameUtils.directoryContains(final String canonicalParent, final String canonicalChild)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't have the name of the folder and the file may not exists.

Comment: You mean, you are checking the full file name, kind of "D:\test\base\some_image_file.JPEG"?

Comment: Yes something like that. But in this case it is possible to extract the folder name by little String manipulation. But the folder can have 30000 or more files. So in that case for each file I need to list all these files!

Comment: You can also try http://commons.apache.org/io/
and use 
    
    FileNameUtils.directoryContains(final String canonicalParent, final String canonicalChild)

Answer (score 0):

The canonical name returns the name with case sensitive. If it returns a different string than the name of the file you are looking for, the file exists with a different case.

So, test if the file exists or if its canonical name is different

```
public static boolean fileExistsCaseInsensitive(String path) {
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        return file.exists() || !file.getCanonicalFile().getName().equals(file.getName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```