# How to check Directory exits with proper case in java

Tags: java

I want to copy one folder to another location in java,
but when I use

```
File f = new File(userInputFilePath);
```

and checks

```
if(f.isDirectory())
```

it returns *true*.

For example for the `userInputPath` as "C:\To\TesT" while the directory path is "C:\to\Test".

Please suggest me ASAP

Comment: Please, make the function behavior clearer (or "Excuse me, WHAT?!")

Comment: Why do you care about that? Windows folder names are by default case insensitive.

Comment: You are on Windows, and likely on NTFS. Therefore: "In NTFS, you can create unique file names, stored in the same directory, that differ only in case. For example, the following filenames can coexist in one directory on an NTFS volume:
CASE.TXT
case.txt
case.TXT
However, if you attempt to open one of these files in a Win32 application, such as Notepad, you would only have access to one of the files, regardless of the case of the filename you type in the Open File dialog box."

Comment: Ignoring the rude tone, there are already multiple answers to this question, for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620555/case-sensitive-file-extension-and-existence-checking 
Moreover, if your filesystem driver is not case sensitive, as kelunik pointed, there is no point trying to check it (educational purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows systems the case of filenames is irrelevant; try renaming the directory from `Test` to `TesT` and you'll see what I mean. You can of course go against this manually by comparing Strings (something like `f.getPath().equals(userInputFilePath) && f.isDirectory()`) but that's not necessarily a good idea as most programs will not differentiate between the two and this could cause unexpected behavior.