# I wanted to get sub string

Tags: java, string, rcp

Currently I am using code like this

```
    while (fileName.endsWith(".csv")) {
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(FILE_SUFFIX_CSV));
        if (fileName.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

The above code works fine when user specifies extension in small letters(.csv),But windows accepts extensions case sensitive so he can give like .CsV ,.CSV etc. how can I alter above code ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: convert the filename to lower case dude

Comment: This has already been answered here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620555/case-sensitive-file-extension-and-existence-checking

Answer (score 13, accepted):

why don't you turn it to lowercase?

```
while (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")) {
    fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(FILE_SUFFIX_CSV));
    if (fileName.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: `filename.lastIndexOf(...)` has the same problem. This must also be converted to lower case. Besides that: This is the answer!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose this is the answer, unless you need to preserve case in the file name, which is rather likely.

Comment: @ThomasStets With `fileName.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(FILE_SUFFIX_CSV)` you are _not_ changing the variable. You are only changing the calculation of the index. The variable `fileName` is still substituted with a substring of the _original_ string (`fileName.substring(...)`).

Comment: @ThomasStets: indeed, this answer does not subvert the fileName variable whatsoever since Strings **are immutable**. 1+ to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Late night regex solution:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".csv", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
while (matcher.find()) {
    fileName = fileName.substring(0, matcher.start());
    if (fileName.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

The `Matcher` will only `find()` once. It can then report its `start` position which you can use to `substring` the original file name.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way

```
 int lastIndexOfDot=fileName.lastIndexOf("\\.");
 String fileExtension=fileName.substring(lastIndexOfDot+1,fileName.length()); 
 while(fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase(".csv")){

 }
```

Or

```
while(fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith(".CSV"){}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please convert to lowercase and then compare.

```
  while (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")) {
        fileName = fileName.toLowerCase().substring(0, fileName.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(FILE_SUFFIX_CSV));
        if (fileName.toLowerCase().trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert both to uppercase.

So change this line

```
fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(FILE_SUFFIX_CSV));
```

to

```
fileName = fileName.toUpperCase().substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(FILE_SUFFIX_CSV.toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this utility function:

```
public static boolean endsWithIgnoreCase(String str, String suffix)
{
    int suffixLength = suffix.length();
    return str.regionMatches(true, str.length() - suffixLength, suffix, 0, suffixLength);
}
```

now you can do:

```
while (endsWithIgnoreCase(fileName, ".csv")) {
    fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(FILE_SUFFIX_CSV));
    if (fileName.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```